# Dynamically filtering a list of objects c++

Tags: c++, filtering

If I have a class such as:

```
class Car {
  string name;
  int age;
  string manufacturer;
}
```

and I display a list of cars, with a filter drop down containing name, age, manufacturer. How can I compare the respective property on the car?

I could use a switch statement however this would get unmanageable if there were many fields.

In JS or Objective-C (using KVC) you can access the properties of an object dynamically, so this would be easy.

Specifically I am asking what is the equivalent pattern in C++ for accessing a variable or member function that you can't know at compile time because it is provided by the user at runtime.

Comment: in what sense do you want to compare properties? Is it ok if they are always presented as strings?

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a way of (a) determining the properties of the object, and then (b) accessing them so you can compare 2 objects?

Comment: Well it would be nice to be able to determine the properties of the object, but mainly it is the accessing them to compare them that I can't think how to do (that isn't in another language)

Comment: Typically you would create a *comarator* function/functor/lambda for each member you wish to compare.

Comment: @Galik, that sounds like 50+ comparators, when they are like at most 10 different data types. Isn't one of C++'s things to reduce duplicate boilerplate (hence templates)?

Comment: Sorry I realised I put runtime rather than compile time, so it wasn't so clear.

Comment: @Jonathan. Having 50 member variables in a class sounds pretty extreme. Maybe there is a data container more suited to your task?

Comment: There aren't 50 in one class, but there are multiple classes (eg Car, City, Journey)

Answer (score 2):

You would normally use `std::map<>` to store the properties rather than individual data members.

This has the added advantage of allowing properties to be created at runtime, so an entire data model can be dynamic and data-driven.

Comment: Using a map will fix the stored type unless you use something like boost::any. and I wouldn't always choose this way of doing it.

Comment: Yup I thought about this, but the properties are mixtures of strings, ints, dates, etc. as Caribou said.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent pattern built into the language: unlike JS, Objective-C, and other languages with heavyweight metadata, C++ has only limited amount of runtime information available to your code, and it would not be of any help to complete your task.

However, it does not mean that there is no way to build your own metadata. You can make a function that compares a string value to a field of an object, make a map of these functions to their corresponding fields, and use the functions from your map to access fields (as if) by name:

```
// Field equality comparers
map<string,function<bool(Car&,string&)>> carFieldEq = {
    {"name", [] (Car &c, string& cmp) { return c.name == cmp; }}
,   {"age", [] (Car &c, string& cmp) { return to_string(c.age) == cmp; }}
,   {"manufacturer", [] (Car &c, string& cmp) { return c.manufacturer == cmp; }}
};
// Field less-than comparers
map<string,function<bool(Car&,string&)>> carFieldLess = {
    {"name", [] (Car &c, string& cmp) { return c.name < cmp; }}
,   {"age", [] (Car &c, string& cmp) { return c.age < std::stoi(cmp); }}
,   {"manufacturer", [] (Car &c, string& cmp) { return c.manufacturer < cmp; }}
};
```

You can use these maps as follows:

```
auto cars = vector<Car> {
    {"Impala", 10, "Chevrolet"}
,   {"Focus", 3, "Ford"}
,   {"Jetta", 3, "VW"}
};
string fieldNameEq, eqCmp;
cin >> fieldNameEq >> eqCmp;
cout << "==== Cars matching " << fieldNameEq << "==" << eqCmp << ":" << endl;
for (auto &c : cars) {
    if (carFieldEq[fieldNameEq](c, eqCmp)) {
        cout << c.name << " " << c.age << " " << c.manufacturer << endl;
    }
}
string fieldNameLess, lessCmp;
cin >> fieldNameLess >> lessCmp;
cout << "==== Cars matching " << fieldNameLess << "<" << lessCmp << ":" << endl;
for (auto &c : cars) {
    if (carFieldLess[fieldNameLess](c, lessCmp)) {
        cout << c.name << " " << c.age << " " << c.manufacturer << endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/AXBF7N)

Note that `carFieldEq` and `carFieldLess` take an arbitrary string, which may not necessarily match the actual name of the field.

Comment: That would work for equality, but you couldn't filter say all cars with `age < 10`

Comment: @Jonathan. This is only a demo that shows you how to start building your own metadata. You can make a similar map for functions that take a car and an integer value, and return `true` or `false` based on whether the corresponding field is smaller or not smaller than the value provided.

Comment: I don't have much time or I'd write the answer ( :P sorry ) but if rather than strings you used an object (variant like boost::any) or possibly functors that grab the values lazily so they are not stored twice it might give the required range of function

Comment: @Caribou I am not sure if boost is a fair game, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yeah :) but I quite like the idea of using something like std::function to point to the comparators / any type of function with your map.

Comment: @Jonathan. Also, you could write a C++ code generator that generated all of the code that you see in the demo code.   The patterns are consistent enough to be able to create such a generator.  You would have a data file describing the field name, its type, etc. and have a program generate the map structure.

Comment: Thanks, that's given me some ideas. This would be a lot easier if C++ had generics rather than templates :/ It all seems quite inflexible because if I want to add more comparisons (>, <, <=, >=, ==, !=, regex) it's a huge amount of code to write/generate.

Comment: @Jonathan. Right, there's definitely a combinatorial explosion here. You could make it easier by going back to the idea of retrieving the value as a string, and writing a bunch of functions that do string comparisons based on the kind of the string (i.e. comparing some strings as strings, while comparing other strings as numbers, depending on the field type that you also put in your metadata).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, losing the type seems wrong, and converting back and forth seems like a great way to get bugs/problems and slow things down.

Comment: @Jonathan. Unfortunately, that's the price you pay for lack of common type ancestor coupled with lack of generics. However, it's not too hard to do it right, as long as the speed is not a big concern. Given that it's for the UI, CPU cycles spent on converting to/from string should not matter at all.